# Getting SnapshotNotFoundException in Spring WebFlow

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflow

I am getting `org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.snapshot.SnapshotNotFound`Exception in production environment, however i am not able to replicate this issue in development environment. Any help on this is appreciated

URL:- `/path?execution=e5s6`

I have defined the Max Snapshot also

```
<webflow:flow-executor id="flowExecutor" flow-registry="flowRegistry" >
   <webflow:flow-execution-listeners>
     <webflow:listener ref="loggingListener"/>
   </webflow:flow-execution-listeners>
    <webflow:flow-execution-repository max-executions="5" max-execution-snapshots="50" />
</webflow:flow-executor>
```

And error stack trace here

```
    org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.snapshot.SnapshotNotFoundException: No flow execution snapshot could be found with id '7'; 
    perhaps the snapshot has been removed? at 
org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.impl.SimpleFlowExecutionSnapshotGroup.getSnapshot(SimpleFlowExecutionSnapshotGroup.java:73) at 
    org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.impl.DefaultFlowExecutionRepository.getFlowExecution(DefaultFlowExecutionRepository.java:111) at 
    org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorImpl.resumeExecution(FlowExecutorImpl.java:168) at 
    org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.handle(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:228) at 
    org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowController.handleRequest(FlowController.java:174) at
```

Comment: try opening a tab with a certain page. then open another window and navigate pages to pages at least 50 times? then go back to the first one and then click on a button or refresh. you can test it with a smaller number in your conf

Comment: this approach didn't helped, i followed the same suggested approach, in fact i got different Exception  `Caused by: java.lang.Exception: org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.FlowExecutionRestorationFailureException: A problem occurred restoring the flow execution with key 'e3s3'`

Answer (score 0):

I think i found the Issue, spring Webflow increments the snapshot every time ex. **url?execution = e1s1, e1s2.....e1s10**.

Now in the URL if we manually enter url?execution=e1s9 no errors, but if we try **url?execution=e1s3** it will give exception. I guess spring webflow keep few snapshot in the memory

Error stack here

```
Caused by: org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.FlowExecutionRestorationFailureException: A problem occurred restoring the flow execution with key 'e7s5'
    at org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.impl.DefaultFlowExecutionRepository.getFlowExecution(DefaultFlowExecutionRepository.java:113)
    at org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorImpl.resumeExecution(FlowExecutorImpl.java:168)
    at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.handle(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:228)
    at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowController.handleRequest(FlowController.java:174)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at com.czen.app.framework.CZenDispatcherServlet.doDispatch(CZenDispatcherServlet.java:102)
    ... 73 more  Caused by: org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.snapshot.SnapshotNotFoundException: No flow execution snapshot could be found with id '5'; perhaps the snapshot has been removed?
    at org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.impl.SimpleFlowExecutionSnapshotGroup.getSnapshot(SimpleFlowExecutionSnapshotGroup.java:73)
    at org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.impl.DefaultFlowExecutionRepository.getFlowExecution(DefaultFlowExecutionRepository.java:111)
    ... 79 more
```

Comment: Yes, `max-execution-snapshots="50"` means that for each execution (and you're currently allowing 5 total), only 50 snapshots will be retained in memory. Once the 51st is created, the 1st is gone, and so on.